# How were WebAPI requests cancelled in the olden days before async/await?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, async-await

In .NET 4.5, using the async/await pattern, a web request can be easily cancelled by including a `CancellationToken` in an async controller method. This of course can be passed to any async Entity Framework methods, and the whole thing can be cancelled nicely.

But going back 6 years, before the days of async, how were WebAPI or MVC controller methods cancelled? Was it even possible? And if so, was it possible to also cancel long-running Entity Framework queries within those cancelled requests?

My motivation for asking is that I've run some experiments and found that in almost all cases, my synchronous versions of large-ish EF queries are faster than their async counterparts. The async versions vary between 10 and 50% longer. Furthermore, my application is for internal use and will realistically only ever serve a maximum of 3 concurrent users, so scalability is a non-issue.

**In short**, I want the speed of the old-fashioned, synchronous Entity Framework methods (and therefore, synchronous controller methods), but with cancellability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But going back 6 years, before the days of async, how were WebAPI or MVC controller methods cancelled? Was it even possible? And if so, was it possible to also cancel long-running Entity Framework queries within those cancelled requests?

Legacy ASP.NET uses `Thread.Abort` to cancel synchronous requests. This of course eventually causes application instability, so ASP.NET will regularly recycle your app domain (and service process).

I'm not sure if legacy ASP.NET uses `Thread.Abort` to cancel asynchronous requests (while they are running code, I mean). I would assume so, but I don't know for sure.

As a final note, please do notify the EF team of your performance issues.